# DOM Based Cross-Site Scripting

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010, javascript-objects

On a security check I found that some pages of my site is not secure in view of DOM Based Cross-Site Scripting.

What Kind of action should I take to secure my site for DOM Based Cross-Site Scripting

PS : I am using asp.net and javasript

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you are actually looking for in an answer? Your question is not even phrased as a question.

Comment: I have edited my question..please look it

Answer (score 1):

This site is very useful about security issues. Have a look at the following topic.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: i want to implement some code to restrict it..do you have any idea how to start with it

Comment: Without seeing the code it is hard to say. You can start with encoding/decoding your html and json entities. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233.1_-_HTML_escape_JSON_values_in_an_HTML_context_and_read_the_data_with_JSON.parse

Comment: This is good, too. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet